# Some reference requests for path algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, reference-request, quiver

I can find some properties and characterizations of path algebras and its elements in representation theory books but I want some references that study and treat path algebras as invertible elements, idempotents, ideals, etc... without focusing on representation theory.

Best regards.

Comment: @DietrichBurde do you know some references that study path algebras and their elements?

Comment: Path algebra elements? Do you mean quivers? Just search for a text on it. Have you seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2646111/can-anyone-suggest-me-some-books-on-leavitt-path-algebra)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks I know this book, I want some references like it but study/focus on path algebras. Currently, I use Google Bard, ChatGPT to answer a simple question `search references that characterize the group of units in path algebras` and non of them give good references.